# webpage not take max screen width?

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to make my webpage take max width and height, for some reason. I have tried various sizing properties of the html, body and div tags but no avail. Does anyone know why? I tried other browsers apart from current Chrome and Edge but get similar effect, it seems to have this white space or border running all around the whole webpage.

```css
.html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-gap: 10px; */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 100px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  height: 100vh;
  /* width: 100vw; */
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* outline: 3px dashed black */
}

[class^='ma'] {
  /* display: grid; */
  /* outline: 3px solid black; */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(187, 233, 239, 0.931);
}

.navbar_top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 55px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> -->
  <title>GameKongWebsite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <div class="ma navbar ">

      <div class=" navbar_top">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="ma content "> why not maxed out</div>

    <div class="ma footer ">hi</div>

  </div>
</body>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the margin of the body tag is taking spaces. Can try to reset your css first or just remove the margin of the body tag [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwjSh.png)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion worked. I first tried removing margin: 0px; from the code but it did not work. Then I added the code you wrote and everything worked perfectly. But I am confused, the body tag is adding 8px margin by itself, I am explicitly telling it margin: 0px; but it still adds it. however your code worked? why?  is this some kind of html bug? so confusing.  Regardless thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @LostinSymbols You were setting `margin:0` to `.body` and not to `body`. That's why the body hat the browser default  of 8px margin and adding the "correct" code for `body` removed the margin.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the `body`'s margin by adding the following code

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And:

- either use `body{...}` instead of `.body{...}`
- or assign the `body` class to you `body` element: `<body class="body">`

Same goes for `html`/`.html`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I removed the body margin as recommended but it did not fix the issue, however the users Huy Tran recommendation worked. Which is baffling.? It would seem you both correctly identified the problem.

Comment: You should add the code, not remove it ;-) I rephrased my answer to make it clearer.